# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Create new project window keeps popping up

Tags: visual-studio, c++

I am trying to create a new `C++` console application project in **visual studio 2015 community**, After setting a project name, when i click `OK` button, the new project window of visual studio disappears and then pops up again. It keeps disappearing and popping again every time i click OK button.

This problem only arises when i try to create a `C++` project. I am able to create `C#` or `python` without any problem.

How can i fix this problem ?

**PS.** I only encountered this problem recently. Before that, i was able to create a `C++` project without any problem.

Comment: can you explain why this problem occurs so i don't encounter it in future ?

Comment: it isn't solved yet. I am trying to repair visual studio instead of re-installing it because re-installing it takes a long time. Are you sure there's no other way to fix this problem ?

Comment: I was thinking of uninstalling `C++` template from visual studio and then reinstalling it but there's no C++ template in visual studio directory where language templates are stored. There are C# and python templates but C++ templates are not showing.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the environment variable

The default value is somehow missing a backslash in the end `\`.

```
VCTargetsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140
```

It should be this way:

```
VCTargetsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer I know, but I found this while searching for the answer, so I figure others will too...

I encountered the same issue today after installing some Python extensions for VS2015.  So resolve, I went to Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs -> Visual Studio 2015 -> Modify -> check the box to include "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" (under "Programming  Languages\Visual C++").  I don't know if that was checked before and somehow got broken when installing the Python extensions, or if "adding" those tools coincidentally reinstalled something else that was broken, but it did the trick.