# MSBuild does not have a microsoft.cpp folder

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, compile, build

I am trying to build some projects with some msbuild and I get an msb4019 error saying stuff like "The imported project "C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found".

All solutions I have seen mention changing some registry entries and environmental variables having to do with C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\, however, this folder simply does not exist for me. I have visual studio professional 2017.

[msbuild folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzySv.png)

Comment: It does not appear you have all the required components required to compile a Visual C++ project installed.  This is due to your `VCTargetsPath` path variable being incorrect.  You might try to simply reinstall the `Visual C++ Windows Build Tools`. Since there are several different solutions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr) might be helpful.  Seems strange the error is for an entirely different version of Visual Studio then you have installed. (VS2017 isn't V120)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Community - Create new project window keeps popping up](https://superuser.com/questions/1163999/visual-studio-2015-community-create-new-project-window-keeps-popping-up)

Comment: I tried reinstalling the build tools and it did not fix the problem. Also I don't see how my question relates to the link you posted. As I said my problem is that the Microsoft.cpp folder does not exist on my machine

Comment: The Stack Overflow question is duplicate of this question, but Stack Overflow questions cannot be used as a duplicate candidate, so I picked a possible duplicate that indicates you need to set `VCTargetsPath` to the correct value.

Comment: setting the env variable did not help, the variable is referencing a directory that doesn't exist on my computer, I added in a picture of how my msbuild folder looks

Comment: It does not exist because it does not appear you have installed the `Visual C++ Windows Build Tools`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time since anyone said anything, but if someone still finds this problem, as I did yesterday, I found the solution on this [website](https://elision.design/en/blog/msbuild-error-and-missing-microsoft-cpp-default-props).

As it turned out, the way to find the file `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` and the folder `Microsoft.cpp` was to look in this location:

```
drive:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\year\edition\Common7\IDE\VC
\VCTargets\
```

as opposed to the common location which is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild` and which didn't contain the folder in my case.

In order to find the folder in that location I had to previously install [Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).

Then I created a system [environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) called `VCTargetsPath` and with the mentioned location as value.

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `Visual C++ Windows Build Tools` installed

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS 2017 installed, then `VCTargetsPath` is removed from the previous version of MSBuild.

You should run MSBuild environment from the VS 2017 switching it to the 2015 mode:

`VS2017InstallDir\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat -vcvars_ver=14.0`

See

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/270758/vc-20153-v1400-v140-toolset-for-desktop-does-not-s.html